# Encoding rules for URL with the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol?

Tags: html, url, uri

Is there any authoritative reference about the syntax and encoding of an URL for the pseudo-protocol `javascript:`?  (I know it's not very well considered, but anyway it's useful for bookmarklets).

First, we know that standard [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) follow the syntax:

```
scheme://username:password@domain:port/path?query_string#anchor
```

but this format doesn't seem to apply here. Indeed, it seems, it would be more correct to speak of **URI** instead of **URL** : [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax) is listed the "unofficial" format `javascript:{body}`.

Now, then, which are the valid characters for such a URI, (what are the escape/unescape rules) when embedding in a HTML?

Specifically, **if I have the code of a javascript function and I want to embed it in a `javascript:` URI, which are the escape rules to apply**?

Of course one could escape every non alfanumeric character, but that would be overkill and make the code unreadable. I want to escape only the necessary characters.

Further, it's clear that it would be bad to use some [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)/[urldecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) routine pair (those are for query string values), we don't want to decode '+' to spaces, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My findings, so far:

First, there are the rules for writing a valid HTML attribute value: but here the standard only requires (if the attribute value if enclosed in quotes) an arbitrary CDATA (actually a [%URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#URI), but HTML itself does not impose additional validation at its level: any CDATA will validate).

Some examples:

```
 <a href="javascript:alert('Hi!')">     (1)
 <a href="javascript:if(a > b && 1 < 0) alert(  b ? 'hi' : 'bye')">   (2)
 <a href="javascript:if(a&gt;b &amp;&&amp; 1 &lt; 0) alert( b ? 'hi' : 'bye')">  (3)
```

Example (1) is valid. But also example (2) is valid HTML 4.01 Strict. To make it valid XHTML we only need to escape the XML special characters `< > &`  (example 3 is valid XHTML 1.0 Strict).

Now, is example (2) a valid `javascript:` URI ? I'm not sure, but I'd say it's not.

From [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt): an URI is subject to some addition restrictions and, in particular, the escape/unescape via `%xx` sequences. And some characters are always prohibited:
among them spaces and `{}#` .

The RFC also defines a subset of `opaque URIs`: those that do not have hierarchical components, and for which the separating charactes have no special meaning (for example, they dont have a 'query string', so the `?` can be used as any non special character). I assume `javascript:` URIs should be considered among them.

This would imply that the valid characters inside the 'body' of a `javascript:` URI are

```
 a-zA-Z0-9 
 _|. !~*'();?:@&=+$,/-   
 %hh : (escape sequence, with two hexadecimal digits)
```

with the additional restriction that it can't begin with `/`.
This stills leaves out some "important" ASCII characters, for example

```
{}#[]<>^\
```

Also `%` (because it's used for escape sequences), double quotes `"` and (most important)  all blanks.

In some respects, this seems quite permissive: it's important to note that `+` is valid (and hence it should not be 'unescaped' when decoding, as a space).

But in other respects, it seems too restrictive. Braces and brackets, specially: I understand that they are normally used unescaped and browsers have no problems.

And what about spaces? As braces, they are disallowed by the RFC, but I see no problem in this kind of URI. However, I see that in most bookmarklets they are escaped as "%20". Is there any (empirical or theorical) explanation for this?

I still don't know if there are some standard functions to make this escape/unescape (in mainstream languages) or some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:` URLs are currently part of the HTML spec and are specified at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsing-the-web.html#the-javascript:-url-special-case